# TDBMemo showing weird output

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, interbase

Using an Interbase database I have an application in which I want to show the contents of an memo field.
I have created a datamodule on which I put a `TIBDatabase`, `TIBTransaction`, `TDataSource` and `TIBTable` all connected. Data comes out, no problems so far.

But when I add a `TDBMemo` to a form and want to show the contents all I get is this;

[image]

I have only set the `DataSource` and `DataField` on the `TDBMemo` so there is no further code involved.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by replacing the `TDBMemo` with an `TMemo` and adding the contents to it with;

```
 Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myQuery.FieldByName('myField').AsBytes);
```